# How can I make this v-tabs Vuetify.js component work?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have  [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/tabs#example-2) `v-tabs` component added on a page.

In the example there's only 1 block of data (`text`) binded to the component (all 3 tabs display this `text` data):

```
<template>
  <v-tabs fixed centered>
    <v-tabs-bar class="cyan" dark>
      <v-tabs-slider class="yellow"></v-tabs-slider>
      <v-tabs-item
        v-for="i in items"
        :key="i"
        :href="'#tab-' + i"
      >
        {{ i }}
      </v-tabs-item>
    </v-tabs-bar>
    <v-tabs-items>
      <v-tabs-content
        v-for="i in items"
        :key="i"
        :id="'tab-' + i"
      >
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tabs-content>
    </v-tabs-items>
  </v-tabs>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        items: ['Item One', 'Item Seventeen', 'Item Five'],
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

How do I display a separate block of data in each tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want everything to be abstracted away into the `data` section then you can do something like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Leyoqz :

```
<template>
  <v-tabs fixed centered>
    <v-tabs-bar class="cyan" dark>
      <v-tabs-slider class="yellow"></v-tabs-slider>
      <v-tabs-item
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
        :href="'#tab-' + item.id"
      >
        {{ item.title }}
      </v-tabs-item>
    </v-tabs-bar>
    <v-tabs-items>
      <v-tabs-content
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item"
        :id="'tab-' + item.id"
      >
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ item.text }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tabs-content>
    </v-tabs-items>
  </v-tabs>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        items: [
            {
                title: "First Item",
                text: "This is the first text",
                id: 1
            },
            {
                title: "Second Item",
                text: "This is the second text",
                id: 2
            },
            {
                title: "Third Text",
                text: "This is the third text",
                id: 3
            },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Or, if you don't need it to be dynamic, then you can just hardcode it all in like this:

```
<v-tabs fixed centered>
<v-tabs-bar class="cyan" dark>
  <v-tabs-slider class="yellow"></v-tabs-slider>
  <v-tabs-item href="#tab-1">
    Tab One
  </v-tabs-item>
   <v-tabs-item href="#tab-2">
    Tab Two
  </v-tabs-item>
   <v-tabs-item href="#tab-3">
    Tab Three
  </v-tabs-item>
</v-tabs-bar>
<v-tabs-items>
  <v-tabs-content id="tab-1">
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>This is the first tab</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tabs-content>
  <v-tabs-content id="tab-2">
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>This is the second tab</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tabs-content>
  <v-tabs-content id="tab-3">
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>This is the third tab</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tabs-content>
</v-tabs-items>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand how tabs work with a loop. I couldn't quite get how to use the id, before. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

For using custom components inside each tab in vuetify in 2020 use:

```
   <v-container>
    <v-tabs centered>
      <v-tabs-slider/>
      <v-tab>Tab1</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Tab2</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Tab3</v-tab>

      <v-tab-item>
        <MyView1 />
      </v-tab-item>
      <v-tab-item>
        <MyView2 />
      </v-tab-item>
      <v-tab-item>
        <MyView3 />
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
  </v-container>
```

Comment: Jesus, why was it so hard to find a simple example that actually worked? Thanks.

Comment: this needs to be added in the vuetify docs

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `dynamic component` tab content binding. which gives you more flexibility and control.

[Vue JS Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

[Live Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/b2qj69o1/)